# Utilizando distinct com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho um objeto com uma estrutura mais ou menos assim:

- Data
- Descrição

Estou pensei um `distinct()` no campo descrição pois os registros estão ridiculamente repetidos.

A pergunta é, o `distinct()` considera apenas o primeiro ou o último registro?

Comment: Poderia exemplificar o que possui e mostrar o que gostaria de obter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele considera todas as colunas que estão no select.

```
Select Data, Descricao from ....

data1 teste
data2 teste
data3 teste
data4 teste
```

Nesse caso acima o distinct não mudaria nada no resultado.

Comment: Pode por favor atualizar sua resposta colocando dentro de um escopo do Entity Framework? Dei uma chamada de atenção no autor da pergunta, que não formulou muito bem o que queria.

Answer (score 0):

Minha pergunta não ficou tão clara, de toda a forma a resposta do Ricardo me ajudou em um conceito geral.

A minha resolução foi bem alternativa, segue:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria interessante, ao invés de você bater uma foto com o código, colocar o código como texto pra que outras pessoas possam copiar e colar o texto. Serviria de maior ajuda desta forma. De qualquer forma, vou fazer uns ajustes na sua pergunta pra ela ter uma abrangência maior pra comunidade.